# Node.js Typeerror connect-flash

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash

I'm having trouble showing flash messages with Node.js, Express and Connect-Flash.

I can show error messages for example, but if I want to send more than one message (e.g. a success message if an update was successful or an error message if there was a problem with the update) then I have problems.

**Here's the error:**

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s15/sh/5160abda-ddac-405c-9ea5-3563f3c39a02/7576bce006e47a8b1ea0346472996550

**And here's snippets of my code:**

```
// Routes.js

// ======================================
    // CHANGE PASSWORD
    // ======================================
    app.get('/password', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

        res.render('password', {
            user: req.user, // get the user out of session and pass to template
            error: req.flash('error'),
            success: req.flash('success')
        });
    });

app.post('/password', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

        // Save settings
        if (req.body.newPassword == req.body.confirmNewPassword) {

            User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function (err, user) {

                user.local.password = generateHash(req.body.newPassword);

                user.save(function(err) {

                    if (err)
                        throw new Error('There was a problem saving the password');

                    req.flash('success', 'Password updated successfully')
                    req.user = user;
                    res.redirect('password');
                });

            });

        } else {
            req.flash('error', 'Passwords did not match');
            res.redirect('password');
        }
    });

// Jade template
// ===================

- if (error) // GET ERROR ON THIS LINE <------------
  div.alert.alert-warning #{error}
- elseif (success)
  div.alert.alert-success #{success}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. Here's what I did:

**routes.js**

```
// ======================================
// CHANGE PASSWORD
// ======================================
app.get('/password', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

    var flash = req.flash();

    res.render('password', {
        user: req.user,
        flash: flash
    });
});
```

**password.jade**

```
    if flash.error
      div.alert.alert-danger #{flash.error}
    else if flash.success
      div.alert.alert-success #{flash.success}
```